# How to slide to top a div when click on one team name

Tags: angularjs, css

**CSS**

```
.hover-div{
    position:absolute;
  margin-top:-150px;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.team_hover:hover + .hover-div {
    margin-top:0px;
    visibility:visible;
 }
.hover-div:hover {
    margin-top:0px;
    visibility:visible;
 }
  .slide-hidden{
    visibility:hidden !important;
    transition:all 0.5s linear 0s;
 }
```

Here when mouse over the yellow box. another slide will comes from top. That slided div contain team names. I need to slide back the div when click on one team name. Now its just hide only(ie no slide animation). I need slide effects.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8sIgx0eAHyLzuxesP4G?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on `:hover`, you should add/remove a class on `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave`. I have made a quick edit to your plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/niHQfuDxxV1bv1gcPL73?p=preview

Comment: It would be better to use `ng-click` instead of `ng-mouseover` for better user experience. Using `ng-mouseover` will result in repetitive slide effects until the mouse is completely removed from the div.